# Why does my newly built shared library in the build directory have a different set of dependencies compared to the copy in the install directory?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, shared-libraries

Can anybody tell me why the shared library in my build path has a different set of dependencies to the shared library in my install directory?

```
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/libOmexMeta/cmake-build-release-wsl-ubuntu1804-gcc101/lib$ pwd
/mnt/d/libOmexMeta/cmake-build-release-wsl-ubuntu1804-gcc101/lib
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/libOmexMeta/cmake-build-release-wsl-ubuntu1804-gcc101/lib$ build_dir=/mnt/d/libOmexMeta/cmake-build-release-wsl-ubuntu1804-gcc101/lib
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/libOmexMeta/cmake-build-release-wsl-ubuntu1804-gcc101/lib$ install_dir=/mnt/d/libOmexMeta/install-ubuntu/lib
```

```
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/libOmexMeta/cmake-build-release-wsl-ubuntu1804-gcc101/lib$ ldd -d $build_dir/libOmexMeta.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffffd3fb000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f417fb20000)
        libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007f417f8e3000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f417f5da000)
        libdb-5.3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.3.so (0x00007f417f231000)
        libpq.so.5 => /home/ciaran/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x00007f417ed06000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f417eb02000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f417e72e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f417e390000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f417e178000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f417dd87000)
        libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f417d9cf000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f417d7b2000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f417d58c000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f417d36d000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f418089c000)
        libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f417b7c4000)
```

compared with

```
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/libOmexMeta/cmake-build-release-wsl-ubuntu1804-gcc101/lib$ ldd -d $install_dir/libOmexMeta.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe5c1c7000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fa93452b000)
        libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007fa9342ee000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fa933fe5000)
        libdb-5.3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.3.so (0x00007fa933c3c000)
        libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5 (0x00007fa9339ee000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa9337ea000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa933416000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa933078000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa932e60000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa932a6f000)
        libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007fa9326b7000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa93249a000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fa932274000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa932055000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fa931dc8000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fa9318fd000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fa9316b2000)
        libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fa931460000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa9352a7000)
        libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007fa92f8b7000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fa92f5e1000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fa92f3af000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fa92f1ab000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fa92efa0000)
        liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fa92ed92000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fa92eb77000)
        libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007fa92e95c000)
        libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007fa92e71b000)
        libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fa92e3b5000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fa92e1b1000)
        libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007fa92dfa8000)
        libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007fa92dd1b000)
        libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007fa92da79000)
        libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007fa92d843000)
        libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007fa92d62d000)
        libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fa92d2fe000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fa92d0e1000)
        libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fa92cd63000)
        libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fa92cb50000)
        libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007fa92c91a000)
        libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007fa92c6e6000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fa92c465000)
        libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007fa92c23c000)
        libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007fa92c02d000)
        libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007fa92bde3000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fa92bbab000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fa92b9a3000)
```

These are newly built binaries so I don't understand why these are different.

Comment: All (?) the added libraries seem to be related to crypto / security...

Comment: ? because they were build differently.

Comment: No, they were built with the *same* call to cmake - note this is my own library I'm building. This is why I'm confused.

Comment: `the same call` What _call_ exaclty? Please be specific. Please post an [MCVE]. Well, you can drive the same car, but you are going to drive differently in a desert and in a city. The _call_ (which you didn't show, so I do not know what it is) could be the same, but the _environment_ (and configuration) could be different.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in to try and help me out, but honestly, sometimes a full minimal example is just not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `ldd`, you see not only your direct dependencies, but the indirect dependencies of your dependencies.  The libraries that your shared library depends on have different dependencies in the two different locations.

In particular, in one location it's resolving libpq.so.5 using

`libpq.so.5 => /home/ciaran/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libpq.so.5`

while in the other it's

`libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5`

which in turn brings in different sets of libraries.

Comment: Interesting spot there. So it seems that my issue is an `RPATH` one. I think what is happening is `$ORIGIN` is not configured correctly. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with KamilCuk.

Although both files have the same name, they might be different. Use `md5sum` to check this.

To avoid `RPATH` side-effects, use `ldd -r option`.

Comment: I can confirm that the two files have different md5sum output. Which is confusing since `libOmexMeta` is the new library that I am building. I'm deleting all build files and starting again. Perhaps I've mixed up old and new builds.